# Library Linking Error on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS when compiling

Tags: c++, compilation

I am using ubuntu 12.04 upgraded gcc to 4.7, somehow when I compile (my Makefile FC use gfortran) under user, it says:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [build/x86_64/bin/libalgebra.0ae9caadf83b653d634cfc68d8570085.so] Error 1
```

I re apt-get it, still the same, why I couldn't link to it?

Answer (score 0):

You have `pkg-config` available to you. It is very neat for these situations.

```
 $pkg-config[Tab][Tab]
```

will autocomplete every includeable installed library on your system. Find the Fortran library in this list at your leisure.

To get the necessary linker flag use

```
$pkg-config --libs gfortXX(library name)
```

I don't have this lib installed on my system, so I can't tell you the exact output. But as an example, I need to get the linker flags for the harfbuss library:

```
CptTall@kipling:~$ pkg-config --libs harfbuzz
-lharfbuzz
```

Also the man page is quite useful. It is not "BSD"-well written, but overall useful.

You can also get the compiler flags by `pkg-config --cflags libname`.

Comment: When I use: pkg-config --libs gtkxxx or gfortranxxx, it says: Package xxx was not found in the pkg-config search path. What should it add and export in the .profile under user?

Comment: All properly installed libs registers those paths

Comment: It's under usr/bin/gfortran, how to link to it, I am compiling under a user, do I put in in .profile and export it?